# Does fusion tables support inserts with times?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm using the query API to insert a datetime with this format: '2013-06-25T21:57:25.033-07:00'

But in the table it only shows up with date-precision, the time is dropped. How can I include the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the column to the correct date format on the Fusion Table in question.

Open Google Fusion Table Interface > Change Column > Select Date/Time Column > Select Appropriate Date Format: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUz4N.png